# KeyError when applying a function to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with two columns initially.'Col 1' has only two values for entire dataset - X and Y. In this example, I want values of 'Col 3' to be filled with 1 for index '3' to index '7'. Then for index '9' to index '10' to be filled with 2 and for index '12' to be filled with 3. So basically for every change in X, I like to fill it's corresponding value in 'Col2' for the new column 'Col 3' like the example below:

[image]

I have applied this code in Pandas

```
col3 = pd.Series([], dtype='float')
count = 0
i = 0
while count < len(df):
    if ~df['col2'][count].startswith('A'):
        d_value = df['col2'][count]
        if i != len(df)-1:
            while df['col1'][i+1] != 'X':
                col3[i + 1] = d_value
                i = i + 1
    count = i + 1
    i = i + 1
    

df.insert(loc=1, column = 'Col 3', value = col3 )
```

but I am getting an error which is not so clear.
[image]

The code works if I apply in a subset of data (e.g:- For 500 rows) but it gives the error if I apply in the entire dataset. What am I doing wrong in this ?

Comment: kindly provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ifly6, is the edited version ok ? I removed the images of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the conceptual model to vectors, it can be achieved without looping.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Col1": ["X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "Y", "Y", "X", "Y"],
        "Col2": [1, "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", "A15", 2, "A16", "A17", 3, "A18"],
    }
)

# copy across X value to Y for Col3 for first Y row
df = df.assign(
    Col3=np.where(
        df["Col1"].eq("Y"),
        np.where(df["Col1"].shift().eq("X"), df["Col2"].shift(), np.nan),
        np.nan,
    )
)
# complete the Y-rows
df.loc[df["Col1"].eq("Y"), "Col3"] = df.loc[df["Col1"].eq("Y"), "Col3"].fillna(method="ffill")

df
```

#### output

|  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | X | 1 | nan |
| 1 | Y | A11 | 1 |
| 2 | Y | A12 | 1 |
| 3 | Y | A13 | 1 |
| 4 | Y | A14 | 1 |
| 5 | Y | A15 | 1 |
| 6 | X | 2 | nan |
| 7 | Y | A16 | 2 |
| 8 | Y | A17 | 2 |
| 9 | X | 3 | nan |
| 10 | Y | A18 | 3 |